# Proper way to append to a React array state using React Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to implement a simple history of message in React.

I want to use a useEffect Hook that will depend on the `sentMessage` state.
Upon trigger of the effect, I want to append to my history of messages the new value of the sent message.

However, using `setHistoryState((prevValue) => prevValue.push(sentMessage)` is, if I understand well, not the right way to proceed since historyState is not in the dependencies.

What is the correct way to implement this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is not necessary to have `historyState` in `useEffect`'s dependencies to call `setHistoryState`. So I think you could do something like:

```
useEffect(() => {
   setHistoryState(prevValue => [...prevValue, sentMessage]);
}, [sentMessage]);
```

This means that, every time `sentMessage` changes his value, new value will be pushed in `historyState`.

Comment: thank you, but I thought that using   setHistoryState(prevValue => [...prevValue, sentMessage]);    was implicitly using the historyState value

Comment: @aurelien_morel no it isn't (if was as you thought, you should get a warning like "missing dependencies on useEffect blablabla")

Answer (score 1):

You could spread the existing history and create a new array with its values, adding a new element in the process.

```
// historyState is an array here
const [historyState, setHistoryState] = useState([1,2,3])

setHistoryState(history => [...history, newValue]);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-browser-v8jp0

Comment: isn't it a problem if I do this inside a useEffect() hook where historyState is not in the dependencies ?

Comment: Maybe you need to add some more context to your question

Comment: thank you for your codesandbox,, here you achieve it without the useEffect (directly using the onClick)
but I can't do this since there are different historyState's coming from different children so I need to use useEffect to react to changes in each of them

Comment: Why can't you set this state within a useEffect?  I don't understand that part.

Comment: because I thought that setHistoryState(history => [...history, newValue]); was using historyState as a dependency, and I can not place it in the dependency list, but it seems that it works actually

Answer (score 1):

From what i see your problem may come frome the fact `prevValue.push` will mutate your state "prevValue". This is not a recomanded way to manipulate states.

You could change your state this way =>

```
setHistoryState((prevValue) => ([...prevValue, sentMessage]))
```

Have a look to "avoid+mutations+js" on google.

Answer (score 0):

You make a copy of its like that

```js
setHistoryState((prevValue) => {
    const value = JSON.parse(JSON.stringiy(prevValue) 
    value.push(sentMessage)
    return value
}
```

You can try another deep copy ways instead using JSON